For which $a > 0$ does $\sin^{n^a} (nx)$ converge almost everywhere?
I'm solving the following problem:

For which $a > 0$ does the sequence $\sin^{n^a} (nx)$ converge almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$?

How can I approach this? I proved that $a = 1$ works (because $\sin^{n} (nx)$ tends to $g(x) = 0$) but how can I generalize it?

Take $x = \pi y$ with y irrational

@julio_es_sui_glace  Take $y=1/\pi$  and $a=1.$ How do you decide whether $\sin^n(n)$  is convergent or divergent ?

@RyszardSzwarc it was more of an idea than a complete answer sorry… you need to ajust it a little bit so that you don’t have pi in it, you probably need to consider $x \notin \pi \mathbb{Q}$
